# How to Call attribute ( attribute code : product_collection) in a CMS block in magento 2.1 CE

Tags: magento2

Am having attribute called product_collection, want to call this attribute value in cms block and need to display the value in one category. thank you

Comment: You have to call phtml file in cms block, you can attribute code in phtm.

Comment: how to call, am new to this, can you help me. or else is it possible to call attribute in static block first and then we can call the block in category using admin panel..? help me plz

Comment: can any one help.